# using TYPO3 core hooks only in one site of a multi site installation

Tags: typo3

i defined a hook in ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['tslib/class.tslib_content.php']['typoLink_PostProc']['titleTagsInHiddenText'] = SNM\StmwiAccessibility\ExtendTypolink::class . '->convertTitleInHiddenText';
```

This hook will be executed on every link on the page, on all pages of all sites. This could be a performance killer ...

So, is there a possibility to restrict the use of the hook to the actual page? Is it possible to get the current site in ext_localconf.php?

e.g.:

```
$currentSite = ????;
if ($currentsite = 'rootPidOfMySite') {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']
}
```

This question rises in other contexts too: i often want to restrict the performance consuming configuration of extensions to one single site. I can do it with the static setup file but not with the stuff in ext_localconf.php.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which TYPO3 version do you use? There is an API to access the site configuration. I'd say you need to register PSR-15 middleware and then you can access the site configuration. More details can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AccessingSiteConfiguration.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use TYPO3 10.4 ... you mean, i should register a middleware, get the site definition and then register the hook straight in this middleware? Perhaps possible - the question is: is $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS'] already defined when the middleware runs? Well, i can try it.

Comment: JEPP. It works - thanks for this hint, Peter! I registered a middleware at the end of the middleware chain (no need to register it more early) and registered in this middleware the hook after checking the site. Nice!